# JWT in Laravel and Angular on many VPS

Tags: laravel, jwt, single-sign-on

I implemented JWT on the first VPS. On this server, I have controllers in Laravel and a database where users are stored. Now I want to add JWT on the second VPS. But JWT should get users from the first server. It should be something similar to login with a google password on different services or devices.
How to implement JWT on every next VPS? Are there any best practices for this solution?
On the second VPS, the user should only type his email address and login without entering the password if he is logged on the first VPS.
The first VPS should have some API, and when the user type an email on the second VPS it should ask the first VPS if a user is logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are talking about SSO.
I did make a SSO feature using laravel passport.

So, the idea is you have a central app that handles authentication.
Any application that to login is considered a client. So, they will verify themselves as a valid client then you may obtain a user token from the client.

You may have a study on oauth2, passport.